# textbook formula for the pdf of a noncentral chi distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request

I am looking for a textbook reference of the pdf of the noncentral chi distribution. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution) says it is

$p(x) = \frac{e^{-(x^2+\lambda^2)/2}x^k\lambda}
{(\lambda x)^{k/2}} I_{k/2-1}(\lambda x)$
with lambda the non centrality parameter and k the number of degrees of freedom.

While the book I looked up (Detection of Signals in Noise by A. Whalen, https://www.elsevier.com/books/detection-of-signals-in-noise/whalen/978-0-12-744850-3) has a different formulation with a square root inside the bessel function for the two parameters. I tried plugging in some numbers in, and they obviously give me different results. However, they both integrate to 1 from 0 to something like 10**10, so they might be different parametrisation of the same formula. 
They indicate that the pdf is

$p(x) = x \left(\frac{x^2}{\lambda}\right)^{(n-2)/4} e^{(-\lambda/2 -
 x^2/2)} I_{n/2-1}((x^2\lambda)^{1/2})$
with lambda the non centrality parameter, n the number of degrees of freedom and $I_v(x)$ the modified bessel function of order v for argument x. Does anyone know which parametrisation the book might be using (since it is an exercise, they don't really mention it) or another textbook reference I could look into to double check the formula?

Can't post picture, so here is a screenshot from the book http://i67.tinypic.com/3144av5.png

Comment: How is the chi² distribution defined in this book? It's often $\sum X_i$ with independent $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, 1)$ and $\lambda = \sum \mu_i^2$, but some references take $\sqrt{\lambda}$ or $\lambda/2$ as the noncentrality parameter.

Comment: Seems like they define $\lambda=\sum x / \sigma^2$ as the centrality parameter and a new variable $x = s/\sigma^2$, maybe the book is doing things a bit special compared to the other books. I could redo the derivation by hand for the book from noncental chi suaqre to noncentral chi, same for wikipedia, but not the link between the two so far.